# Evaluate$ \oint _{|z|=1} \frac{\log\ |1-z|}{z}dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Evaluate

$$ \oint _{|z|=1} \frac{\log\ |1-z|}{z}dz $$
**My Attempt**
$$ I=\oint _{|z|=1} \frac{\log\ |1-z|}{z}dz $$
$$z=e^{i\theta} \Rightarrow dz =i e^{i\theta}d\theta$$
$$I=i \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log\  |1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta$$
$$\text{ define }\, f(z)= |1-z|$$
$f(0)=1$

Now, $f(z)=0$ gives $z=1$.

**By Jensen's Formula,**
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log\  |1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta = \log |f(0)|+\log(1)$$
$f(0)=1$ gives,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log\  |1-e^{i\theta}|d\theta =0$$
$$I=0$$

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the edit. Please answer.

Comment: You're welcome....with a lot of sincerity I am not able :-(...I had only voted up your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all $\frac{\log\ |1-z|}{z}$ is integrable on $|z|=1$ (it is continuous away from a logarithmic singularity at $z=1$)

$$\int _{|z|=1} \frac{\log\ |1-z|}{z}dz=i \Im(\int _{|z|=1} \frac{\log(1-z)}{z}dz)=\lim_{r\to 1} i\Im(\int _{|z|=r} \frac{\log(1-z)}{z}dz)=0$$
by the Cauchy integral theorem (as $\frac{\log(1-z)}{z}$ is analytic for $|z|<1$)

Comment: Explain this step $$\Im(  \int _{|z|=r}\frac{\log(1-z)}{z}dz)=     \lim_{r\to 1} \Im(\int _{|z|=r} \frac{\log(1-z)}{z}dz)$$. How can we take limit outside the closed integral?

Comment: Remove of a small piece of the circle around $r$ (and $1$) the equality is obvious (by continuity) and the removed piece has a low contribution because our function is integrable around $z=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So continuity of the function implies that we can take limit inside the contour integral?